# EXCEL extend the Menu by an own section how do I this

Tags: excel, menu

I have a EXCEL Workbook with tables for book keeping. And a Macro to book with sevaral Subs up to now the user has to start this Macro, I want to keep away the user from the tables, to hinder him to enter data inconsistent. Is there a way to extend the horizontal menu bar by an own section. And how can I realize this.

Comment: The "horizontal menu" is to name profesionaly  "Ribbon"

Comment: I loaded down the ResEdit -x64 and unpacked into an own carpet I use to do this In this carpet I got the OfficeRibbonXEditor.exe and choosed during the installation to create an Icon on the desktop. I started this application an with the open button I loaded my workbook of book keeping and found in the Help-Ribon of OfficeRibbonXEditor an item "Useful Links" the first option "Change the Ribbon in EXCEL 2007 and up" called my interest, I will report in another coment what there I lived

Comment: This link open the website "Excel Automation" where Ron de Bruin recomend the release of Andreu and to enter the code

Comment: Dude, you need to calm down and not spread comments and posts all over the place. Instead, focus on one thing at a time. You have totally wrecked this thread by posting all over it and nobody knows where to look now to help you.

Comment: Hi Tyly, you are absolutly right, you helped me enough, thank you. Now I think I should load down the Office RibonX Editor as I found in the Website of Ron de Bruin for elderly Office versions, I'm shure this is my problem. Greetings and thank's a lot, Im Wolfgang from Berlin. From now on I'll be more patient.

Answer (score 1):

Three options spring to mind:

- Use shapes or buttons in the worksheet and assign macros to these buttons.
- You can easily add your macros to the ribbon. Create custom groups in any ribbon, or add new ribbon tabs for your macros. Then choose your macros from the command dropdown.
- For more sophistication you can use the free add-in RibbonX Editor: https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/tag/v1.8.0

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thank you Tylyn for your extraordinary answer. I'm trying out your ozeanic solucion

Comment: Yet it doesn't work but I don't know what to do after having entered the Code for the customUI I just saved in the Ribbon Editor and closed the Editor then I tried out what now would happen opening the workbook NIHIL!

Comment: Maybe you need to study the ribbon editor documentation to learn how to use it properly. If you have problems with that approach, you may want to ask a new question after you've finished the paperwork for this one.